# Calculating a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have tried searching but was not able to find a question similar to mine. The question is as:

Consider the matrix

$$ A= \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 3 & 5\end{bmatrix}$$

Let

$$ D= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$

be a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of T as its diagonal entries, and

$$ P= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Calculate the matrix $PDP^{-1}$.

I have no idea how to begin this practise problem. Normally I would just multiply the 3 matrixes, but then it starts talking about eigenvalues of T. Which completely confuses me. May someone give me a hint?

Comment: Notice that the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors of $A$. What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $PDP^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

$$ P^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \end{bmatrix}$$

Multiply the three matrices, and be baffled by the result (optional). Now, notice $P$'s columns are made of linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$. Can you explain the result?

Comment: I think I understand what is going on here, except the reason for having the inverse of P. 
What is the reason that the product of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues multiplied by the inverse of the eigenvector equals A? Is there a formula or something I might've missed out on?

Comment: Notice how both $P$ and $P^{-1}$ are change of basis matrices. The reason the the multiplication equals $A$ is that, in a certain convenient basis (composed of eigenvectors of $A$), matrix $A$ is diagonal (with its entries being its eigenvalues). The multiplication by both $P$ and $P^{-1}$ represents the fact that you're going from cannonical to eigenvector basis, applying the transformation, and returning to the cannonical basis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What happens when you diagonalize A? i.e. $A = PBP^{-1}$ (where the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ and B is a diagonal matrix consists of the eigenvalues of $A$).